# Upload image as byte[] via Spring Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to upload an image file as a `byte[]` object. At the web service, convert this `byte[]` into `BufferedImage` and perform some processing before returning the `byte[]` as a response to the client.

But I am always getting null pointer when `ImageIO.read(byte[] input)` is called. I noticed that the `byte[]` length before and after invoking the service is different. Please help. Following the codes for the client and the rest web service.

client code:
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = null;

```
    final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/core/uploadForMarkImg";

    File source_imgFile = new File("C:\\watermarktest\\source.jpg");


    try
    {
    ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source_imgFile);

    Iterator<ImageReader> imageReaders = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);

    while (imageReaders.hasNext()) {
        ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) imageReaders.next();
        System.out.printf("formatName: %s%n", reader.getFormatName());
    }
    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try
    {

    BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(source_imgFile);
    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", bos);
    bos.flush();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

httpclient = HttpClients.custom().build();
    HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE).addBinaryBody(
            "imgFile", bos.toByteArray(), ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, source_imgFile.getName()).build();

    post.setEntity(entity);
```

Server Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadForMarkImg", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/octet-stream" })
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> imgMark(@RequestBody byte[] imgFile) {


    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File watermarkImageFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("watermark.png").getFile());


        System.out.println("input file length " + imgFile.length);
        BufferedImage resizeOriginal = null;
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imgFile);
        BufferedImage sourceImage=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgFile));
System.out.println("converted to buffer image completed for source image " + sourceImage);

        BufferedImage watermarkImage = ImageIO.read(watermarkImageFile);

        System.out.println("converted to buffer image completed for watermark image " + watermarkImageFile);

        System.out.println("SouceImage Size Width: " + sourceImage.getWidth());
        System.out.println("SouceImage Size Height: " + sourceImage.getHeight());
```

sourceImage.get will always get nullpointer errror.

Comment: take file as MultipartFile then convert it to byte[] and perform your business actions.

Comment: problem is the client cannot generate the multipart file, it only has a byte[] object for the service.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code, you are trying to write the images bytes under `imgFile` multipart. Hence, when you want to retrieve those bytes, it should be via that part itself.

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadForMarkImg", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/octet-stream" })
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> imgMark(@RequestParam(value="imgFile") MultipartFile[] files) {
```

First element would give you the file. Or may be array is not required at all. Try this out.

Comment: hi thanks for the response! i tried to change the input types, but getting the following error: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/core] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request] with root cause
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request, please let me know for the client codes that required to change

Comment: Do yu have Fiddler, run a sample request. And capture and view the packet from client, it would solve the mystery. Share that and I can help further.

Comment: i tried converting the byte[] to an image file but it is not working on the server side. but when i tried to convert the byte[] on the client side before posting to the server, its perfectly fine. so after posting to the server side, somehow the byte[] is not correct already. any idea why the byte[] is somehow different after http post?